# How to Compare Time with Current time & display result based on that using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, time, compare

I have a mysql database with a table structure like below :

```
Table Name : shop_mst
Fields : 
shop_name     varchar(100)
start_time    time
close_time    time
```

Time is stored in 24Hour format. Now I want to create a sql query to display all the records but show Shop status as Open/Closed based on current time. So if the current time comes in between start_time & close_time, then it should show "Open" with Shop name. And if it is not, it should show "Closed" with Shop name. How can I do that? I also want to compare Day with a field in another table but that part I will do myself :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can learn MySQL and whatever other language you're doing.  On a more helpful note though, just use a CASE, or preferably process it in the language you're using to use SQL, not actually in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :

```
select shop_name,if(left(curtime(),5) between start_time  and close_time ,'Open','Closed') as status 
from tablename
```

Assuming you storing star_time and close_time in 18:30,16:15 ... Format.

Comment: you can just use curtime() instead of left(curtime(),5) then